# Plural form of these two sentences

Tags: american-english, grammatical-number

I'm helping my cousing with some English exercises but I don't imagine what would be the plural form of these two sentences:
What is this?

What is that?

I'd say:" What are these?" and "What are those?"
Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; does it not make sense?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that, since I'm not english-native speaker... Thanks anyway! :)